# Re-use report in modal page to show different tables

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm working in Apex 5

I have a modal page, with a report.

It is the simplest report. It just shows columns from a table.

But I want to re-use the same modal page to show any table with the same structure.

One thing I could do is to pass the table name to the modal page, when I call the page.

The problem is that it becomes a target for SQL injection. If I pass the table name, anybody could change the name, and watch another table.

What is the general solution for this problem?

---

I had been asked to post code, so, I may have 10 tables with this format:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
( 
  column1 varchar(20)
  column2 number
);
```

The modal page is a report with this query:

```
SELECT column1, column2
from table1
```

I have 10 tables with the same column names. Each table is named:

```
copper
explain
fated
truck
neat
unite
branch
educated
tenuous
hum
decisive
notice
```

And I want to use the same modal page to display all of the tables.

I have 10 buttons on the application (on different pages), one for each table, which open the modal page.

I made an example application in apex.oracle.com

Workspace: nekagav_ws

User:test

pass:test

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @ ZF007 I edited the question. Is ok now?

Comment: Its a good start. If you have tried preventing code injection based on other examples, suggestion or your own report that as well (e.g. referral links). It shows you tried but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the general solution for this problem?

Example you created doesn't really reflect what you described (no different buttons; it is unclear what you exactly pass to page 3 as button navigates to it, but no values are passed over there).

Therefore, I was free to modify your application and did the following:

- created P3_TABLE_NAME hidden item
- report type is now "Classic report (based on function)"
- query is `return 'select COLUMN1, COLUMN2 from ' || :P3_TABLE_NAME;`
- Use Generic column names is set to "Yes", with 2 generic columns
- region's "Server-side condition" is set to "PL/SQL Function Body and
  it names only valid table names, such as `return lower(:P3_TABLE_NAME) IN ('copper', 'explain', 'fated');`
- on P1, button now redirects to Page 3 but passes P1_LIST_OF_TABLES to
  P3_TABLE_NAME
- on P1, Select list item must have the same *display* and *return*
  values; you can't pass a number (12) which is then used as a table
  name on Page 3 - must be "copper" (for example).

That's more or less all; have a look, adjust it if you have to.

Comment: I emulated multiple buttons with a select list and a single button. There is any difference?

Comment: Select list is maybe easier to maintain in case the list of tables changes as you'd add or remove a table from a query. With multiple buttons, there's more job to be done.

Answer (score 2):

APEX has a built-in protection for this, called Session State Protection (SSP).  This adds a checksum to URLs based on the values it contains. If the user tries to change a value by manipulating the URL when SSP is being used, the checksum will no longer be correct and an error will be shown instead of the page:

> No checksum was provided to show processing for a page that requires a
>   checksum when one or more request, clear cache, or argument values are
>   passed as parameters.
>
> Contact your application administrator.

To enable SSP properly you need to do three things:

1. Enable SSP at application level: edit the appplication properties and under security set **Session State Protection** to `Enabled`. (Your example app already has this value.)
2. Enforce SSP at page level: edit the **target** page properties (page 3 in your example) and under Security set **Page Access Protection** to `Arguments Must Have Checksum`. (You currently have it set to `Unrestricted`.)
3. Enforce SSP at item level: edit the item properties of the target item (`P3_TABLE_NAME` in your example) and under Security set **Session State Protection** to one of the `Checksum Required...` options. (You currently have it set to `Unrestricted`.) I usually use `Checksum Required - Session Level`.

The reason for the item level setting isn't immediately obvious: if you have set page 3 to require a checksum, why would you also need to protect individual items on that page? The reason is that it is possible to set the session state of an item on any page in the URL.  So if you had another page that had SSP set to unrestricted, a user might be able to construct a URL to go to that page and set `P3_TABLE_NAME` to some value, and then navigate to page 3 without clearing cache or setting a value and see the data for the value they chose.

Comment: This is very important. I wish I could also mark it as answer.